# How can I fix disabled text editor focusing bug in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios15

I think there's a bug that disabled text editor is focussed when I get in and out into another tab. I want to totally disable text editors but I don't know how.
Seeing is believing.

```
struct TabViewWithTextEditor: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            TextEditors()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "text.bubble")
                    Text("Text Editor")
                }
            
            AnotherView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "shippingbox")
                    Text("Empty View")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct TextEditors: View {
    @State var textA: String = "Hello World"
    @State var textB: String = "Placeholder"
    @State var enabled: Bool = true
    
    init() {
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear    // To apply background color.
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Text Editor")
            TextEditor(text: $textA)
                .background(enabled ? .gray : .red)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .disabled(!enabled)
            TextEditor(text: $textB)
                .background(enabled ? .yellow : .red)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .disabled(!enabled)
            Toggle("Enable Text Editors", isOn: $enabled)
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Empty View")
    }
}
```

And it looks like

[image: Demonstrate the bug]

Comment: yeah, very strange bug. I made a few tests, and still cannot "go" to `AnotherView` and back, without the disabling not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is due to `TextEditor` (or `UITextView` at backend) preserves focus, probably due to a bug.

Here is safe workaround - remove focus forcefully *before* disable

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
@FocusState private var focused: Bool

var isEditing: Binding<Bool> {
    Binding(get: { enabled } , set: {
        if !$0 {
            focused = false      // << here !!
        }
        enabled = $0
    })
}

// ...

Toggle("Enable Text Editors", isOn: isEditing)
```

Comment: That's what I intended to. I mean whichever the initial state was, if I disabled the text editor view, it should be not able to type into the text editor. However after I switch a tab and back, the disabled text editor view is focused and also I can type some text in it.